# Redirect non-admin users away from wp-admin/index.php (main dashboard page) to wp-admin/profile.php

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, user-access

I've set it so non-admin user can't see the "Dashboard" link or can't have access to the main "wp-admin/index.php" page. I've also added a [plugin that restrict non-admin users from creating a new page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-restrict-user-add-new-page-capability/). Whenever a non-admin users try to add a new page, they'll be accidentally redirected to "**wp-admin/index.php?permissions_error=true**", which is the main "**wp-admin/index.php**", or "**Dashboard**" page.

How do I restrict access to the wp-admin/index.php (main dashboard page), or redirect them to their wp-admin/profile.php page?

screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]
If someone were smart enough to add "?permissions_error=true" next the the "wp-admin/index.php" in the url address, the would get access to the "wp-admin/index.php" main dashboard page, even if they don't have permission to.

- I've tried adding "Redirect 301 /localhost/ft/wp-admin/index.php?permissions_error=true http://google.com" to the .htaccess file, but it's not working because of the "?permissions_error=true"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to hook in `load-index.php` and redirect non-admin users to their profile. Effectively blocking access to that page. I'm going to wrap the permission check up in a function for this example (we'll use it more than once).

```
function _wpse206466_can_view()
{
    // or any other admin level capability
    return current_user_can('manage_options');
}


add_action('load-index.php', 'wpse206466_load_index');
function wpse206466_load_index()
{
    if (!_wpse206466_can_view()) {
        $qs = empty($_GET) ? '' : '?'.http_build_query($_GET);
        wp_safe_redirect(admin_url('profile.php').$qs);
        exit;
    }
}
```

You might also want to remove the admin index page from the admin menu if the users can't access it. To do that, hook into `admin_menu`, check the capability then remove the page.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'wpse206466_remove_index');
function wpse206466_remove_index()
{
    if (!_wpse206466_can_view()) {
        remove_menu_page('index.php');
    }
}
```

Here is all that [as a plugin](https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/WPSE-Plugins/blob/master/no-admin-index.php).

Comment: Hi, I thought it worked, but then tried to access the wp-admin/index.php today as admin and was redirected to profile.php. It work and redirected non-admin users to their profile page, but it's not allowing admin to the main dashboard page. I've even tested the code and the plugin on a fresh wordpress site.

Comment: There was a small typo in my code. See: https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/WPSE-Plugins/commit/8d1dfba594350249fb43ebf49128cf8a3053a9fc The code in this post and the plugin on github has been updated